# Lua bindings: table vs userdata

Tags: binding, lua, lua-table, lua-userdata

When making Lua bindings for C++ classes, should I return tables or userdata objects?

Does anyone know any of the pros and cons for each method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend returning userdata. Regardless of approach, there has to be somewhere to put the pointer
to the C++ data, or the actual C++ data itself, and there's nowhere
safe to do this with a table.

Returning tables would make sense in some situations, because they can
be 'annotated' in Lua with extra attributes without one's having to do
anything extra to support this. Unfortunately the C++ object pointer
has to go somewhere, and there's nowhere sensible for it to go other
than an actual entry in the table itself.

This is not a very safe place for it to go. It can be found by Lua
code, and removed or replaced. This could be by accident, or on
purpose, it doesn't really matter.

My preference therefore is to return userdata objects. They can be
made to work like tables if one really must insist upon that, but they
also have a "secret" area (the actual userdata itself) where the C++
object pointer can be stored, safe from overwriting by Lua code.

(Userdata objects also have an "environment" pointer, which is another
place to store object-specific data. As with the userdata payload
itself, this value is inaccessible to Lua code and can't be damaged
that way.)

Comment: In addition to that, userdatas can have a __gc metamethod bound to them so you can let Lua take care of collecting them when they are not referenced anymore.